# access violation with only GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

`Unhandled exception in 0x7B372F75 (ig9icd32.dll) in forespend.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation writing to location 0x07E00000.` i have tried to run `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` but it returned me this error, my program kept running and working, but seems that it wont work properly due to this error.
the glClear is working with other tags inside of it like ´GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT´ and others.
in debug no problem shows up, the error just appear in the middle of the code like this:

[image: error]

If exist an alternative to `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` id like to know.

the code:

```
#include<GL/glfw3.h>
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<chrono>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define WIDTH 320
#define HEIGHT 200

struct key {

};

GLFWwindow* window;
GLFWmonitor* monitor;
bool running = 1, windowed;
std::map<int, key> keyMap;


void update(){}



void input(){}



void draw(){
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

int main() {
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    if (!glfwInit()) fprintf(stderr, "opengl error\n");
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "end", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {std::cout << "window error\n" << std::endl; glfwTerminate();}
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();

    while (running)
    {
        update();
        input();
        draw();
    }


    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();


}
```

Comment: Use `glGetError` to check for errors in OpenGL state. BTW, you say that you had asked similar question before. I do not see it.

Comment: What does `glfwGetError()` return after `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`?

Comment: i asked it but it got blocked saying that i need to add debug details, there were none to add so i wrote i didnt had any, and since it didnt got unblocked i deleted. i tried the `glGetError` right after the `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` and returned me 0 when i put the error to print with `std::cout`. but i also tried what genpfault said and it returned  `The GLFW library is not initialized`, im not sure why this happened if i can code it without any problems, just running is showing these problems. what can i do?

Comment: What OS? Do you have OpenGL compatible gfx driver installed? (beware on windows MS Windows Update usually forces wrong gfx driver from MS with buggy OpenGL to promote  DirectX ...if the case you need to download and install vendor driver manually) ... OK your image suggest Win10 so I would definatelly check the gfx driver

Comment: how do i install opengl? i followed the opengl instructions and i gone to intel download center to download the intel uhd 620 graphics update, but when i runned the installer it said that isnt for my system. there is any other way to install it? my notebook is a NP350XAA-KFWBR the cpu is a i5-8250u... and thank you for telling me about the windows update thing, i didnt knew it

Comment: well... thank you all, i will try to talk with intel support for this, this is probably not a code problem. so if i found the answer i will say it here for more people be able to fix this problem if it happens with them

Answer (score 0):

well...  i looked for any solution, talked to intel support and it just resulted in they saying i need to get the driver with my notebook provider (samsung) since the installed windows is the one installed in fabric, i have tried to update the drivers with samsung update and it installed an older driver. the error kept happening, since i was starting this week with opengl and was getting this problem since the beginning now i decided to move to another renderer, that is vulkan. it works fine now, so if youre new in opengl and get this problem, i think vulkan is a great option to overcome this since it runs faster and have a great compatibility with windows,ios, linux and android and if the code is for older machines or you really need opengl, so i must say that youd need a virtual machine for this unhappily. in my case i cant use VM because this notebook is low spec